# What is the largest jump in LEGO instructions?

Tags: building, instructions

What is the largest gap in LEGO instructions in terms of build time needed to complete a step? For example, [Skyline (5526)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5526-1#T=S&O=%7B"iconly":0%7D) includes this step:

[image: 5526 step 15]

That is quite a leap between steps 14 and 15. I'm curious to know if any sets leave more up to the builder than this.

I saw this over on Reddit and thought it might be interesting to get answers over here.

Comment: Urgh, that set + instructions looks like a nightmare build.

Comment: Set [8880 - Super Car](http://lego.brickinstructions.com/lego_instructions/set/8880/Racing_Car) Although the parts per instruction have a relatively small number, it can take a long time working out what part out of the list goes where.  It turns into a prolonged "spot-the-difference" contest with the previous page to get anywhere.

Comment: I haven't looked at the 10214 London Tower Bridge instructions, but those maybe leave out many steps describing the second tower. To some degree I noticed this in the instructions for the 70618 Destiny's Bounty when it comes to the second railing which is a mirrored version of the first one.

Comment: @Aziraphale Most of 10214 is actually (x2) instructions :)

Comment: It's difficult to judge build time, would you consider steps that include many bricks to have a long build time?

Comment: Would you consider step 18 in [this set](https://i.imgur.com/1NoaiXJ.png) to be a single step?

Comment: @Ambo100 I think so. This makes me want to pick up some Model Team sets. :) Those were really nice.

Comment: @Ambo100 Is that sub-steps within a sub-step? We need to go deeper!

Answer (score 7):

[Car Chassis 8860](http://www.brickinstructions.com/lego_instructions/set/8860/Car_Chassis) gets my vote for complexity of a single step.

[image]

The instructions are laid out so that you have two pages like this on top of each other.  I was building this model with my 11 year old son recently, and at almost every step on the last couple of pages we found we had missed something from the previous step.